# React routing issue when pass query param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have set Route like

```
    <Route path="/category/:param1?/:param2?/:param3?page=:page&datasetID=:datasetID&graphID=:graphID&year=:year&country=:country" component={Category} />
```

But when I fire url with above path it is not working

Can any one please help me about this?

Comment: Please give an example of the URL you are navigating to (the URL that should match this route), and define exactly what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Here is the example
http://localhost:8080/category/abcd/xyz/test?page=share&datasetID=12&graphID=11&year=2019&country=in,au&type=email

Comment: What do you mean by with about path? You have to rephrase your question otherwise it's going to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) you should do something like this:

```
 <Route path="/category/:param1?/:param2?/:param3?" component={Category} />
```

As for the query params, there's no need to include them on the path. Just get them from your component, as the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) suggest:

```
 let { country, year, graphID, datasetID, page} = useParams();
```

Comment: Thanks @BhojendraRauniyar . Updated my answer removing the question mark part, I think the rest of it still applies

Comment: There's no wrong in OP code either. I think OP is missing exact props that's what may cause problem. But we can't answer without knowing exact detail.